# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle sync fails while trying to build the firebase app!

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:
>   Affected Modules: firebase_core

This is my project-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and app level build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

EDIT: 
The error seems to be due to Flutter Firebase_auth plugin!

Comment: Have you added google-services.json file in the _app_ directory?

Comment: what you need a `firebase_core` module for?

Comment: Already added the File Martin, I was using it for signing in. But the error seems to be with the firebase_auth plugin. Didn't solve the issue though.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.
When I look at the error message in detail, I get the following message.

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0) code here
```

The problem is that the same class exists in the androidx and firebase packages.
Add the following options to the gradle.properties file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

In my case, this was solved.

Answer (score 1):

In project level gradle add following

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this issue was fixed in the 0.3.4 update of firebase_core, which is a dependency of other Flutter Firebase plugins. Try a "flutter packages upgrade" and see if that fixes it for you.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1464/files

Answer (score 0):

Looks like *google-service.json* file is missing or is invalid. Adding *google-service.json* file from the *Firebase* console can fix it.